# Get array inside arrays in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

I have data model structure like this

```
        class Items {
            private var titre:String?
            private var project:[Project]!

   // and getters
    }
and class Project {
    private var auteur:String?
    public var assign: [Assign]?
 //getters
}
```

and array declaration like this `var items = [Items]()`

and i get data from web service so items array look like this< br />

```
items = [[["slow",[Project.class],["bad",[Project.class],["news",[Project.class]]]
```

Now **i want to get one by title for example i want just with title slow** so and the table will be like this `[titre:"slow",[project]`, so how can i do it by swift 3,

I tried to get index and after Fill array with this index but not work for me

```
var abc =  items.index(where: { (item) -> Bool in
                if item.titre == "slow" {
                    return true
                }

                    return false

            })    

 print("item",abc) // i get Optional(1), Optional(1), Optional(1) ... 4 time why ?
```

But this not work for me, if some one can help me to do this and thanks.

Comment: I think, your array structure is wrong. Please check it first.

Comment: What result you are getting with `abc` and what you are expecting?

Comment: @NiravD i get Optional(0)

Comment: @Akram Don't you want object instead of index? you are getting optional because `index(where:)` has return type `Int?`

Comment: yes @Nirav D but this object is an array so it must return the number of index

Comment: @Akram It will return index of first object that has `titre == slow` are you having multiple object with `titre == slow`?

Comment: non @Nirav D i have just one

Comment: @Akram Then it will simply return object of that index with optional

Comment: ok so how can i do it @Nirav D

Comment: @Akram Check my solution.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem. As your question currently stands, it's entirely unclear what your problem is. `[[["slow",[Project.class],["bad",[Project.class],["news",[Project.class]]]` is not a `[Items]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find the index of a particular element and then fill the array with element at that index. You can directly use `filter` methods for this.

The array you provided above is not in the correct format.

**Example**:

```
var arrays = [["titre":"hight"],
              ["titre":"bad"],
              ["titre":"slow"],
              ["titre":"urgency"]]

arrays = arrays.filter({ (element) -> Bool in
    if element["titre"] == "slow"
    {
        return true
    }
    return false
})
```

**Output:**

`arrays` now contains [`["titre":"slow"]]`

Still if you want to use index method, you can use it like:

```
let index = arrays.index { (element) -> Bool in
    if element["titre"] == "slow"
    {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

**Output**:

`index` is now `2`

Answer (score 2):

[`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index) will return optional `Int?` so you can wrapped its value using `if let` or `guard let`.

```
if let index = items.index(where: { $0.titre == "slow" }) {
    //access index here
}
```

If you want simply object from array then you can use [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1848165-first).

```
if let obj = items.first(where: { $0.titre == "slow" }) {
    //access object here
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137358/discussion-on-answer-by-nirav-d-get-array-inside-arrays-in-swift-3).

Answer (score 0):

Use filter to get the result.

```
var filter = array.filter { (item) -> Bool in
    if item["titre"] as! String == "slow" {
        return true
    }

    return false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do to improve this code.

Firstly the tight binding between title and array of project in your code could be a lot clearer if you just wrapped the two in a `Struct`

```
struct MyStruct
{
    let title: String
    let projects: [Project]
}
```

You then only have to contend with a simple 1 dimensional array, and can use a little closure magic to make everything look much sexier:

```
guard let index = array.index(where: {$0.title == "slow"}) else { return }
print("item", index)
```